# console.log does nothing in Firebug in Liferay

Tags: javascript, console, firebug, logging, liferay

I have several debug printouts in my script with `console.log(message)`, but no messages displayed in Console section of Firebug.

What can be a reason for this?

**UPDATE 1**

Neither of `console.warn`, `console.error` and `console.info` works.

**UPDATE 2**

I have a following log function:

```
function log(message) {
   console.error(message);
   $("#log").append(message + "<br/>");
}
```

so it logs both into Firebug console and DIV on page. I see that DIV logging works. Hence the control reaches the statements.

**UPDATE 3**

--irrelevant--

**UPDATE 4**

Update 3 was irrelevant: `consoleBody` in firebug.js was not always null. Later it was becoming valued.

But I saw that the content of `consoleBody` contains "div#log". Probably it interferes with my naming...

**UPDATE 5**

Renaming of ID of my DIV didn't help...

**UPDATE 6**

Whe I do `console.log("hehe")` in immediate line of firebug, it prints `undefined`

**UPDATE 7**

Looks like `console.log()` does not work within Liferay portlet at all; even very simple hello world portlet does not excecute this command.

Comment: Most likely the statements aren't actually reached.  Have you attached a debugger to see where it goes wrong?

Comment: It is very complex script... wait will post something...

Comment: Have you tried breakpointing your code?

Comment: Yes: logging line is reached and just does nothing

Comment: Where are you calling console.log() from? A portlet's JSP? Javascript file? ...

Comment: A javascript file, which is loaded from portlet JSP within `<liferay-util:html-bottom>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the reason for such behaviour for 6.0 version but I have found the reason it doesn't work in 5.2.3.

It seems that Liferay includes Firebug Lite on my page and when I press F12 it appears at the bottom. It does interceps console method calls.

Now I'm looking for correct way to remove the included script.

EDIT:
Seems like the reason for this is that I have developer mode enabled.

set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dexternal-properties=portal-developer.properties

Answer (score 2):

Use `javascript.log.enabled=false` property.
This will disable firebug lite, now `console.log` will log to browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.info`. If that fails, use one of `console.warn` or `console.error`.

There may be a setting to remove this requirement from Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The situation occurs when Liferay 6.0 is running under Eclipse. Eclipse Liferay Plugin upgrade to 1.5 didn't help.

One can set fresh Liferay installation, run it under Eclipse and try `console.log('hehe')` in Firebug's immediate line -- it won't work.

But this bug does not occur in Liferay 6.1 with Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was some bug of Liferay 6.0. Log works in Liferay 6.1

Answer (score 0):

$("#log") does not work in Liferay 5.2. The right syntax (in no-conflict mode) for Liferay is jQuery("#log") as they use multiple js frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has found a way to disable Firebug-Lite completely by renaming the dirname
 webapps/ROOT/html/js/firebug.. It seems to work but I also did what SO user "Yogesh Agrawal" suggested in his answer from Jul 4 at 5:27

See  http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/14202657